# Pandas make column boolean and delete rows that are not

Tags: python, pandas

This is how my pandas dataframe look like:

```
   id       text          country   datetime
0   1      hello,bye         USA    3/20/2016
1   0      good morning      UK     3/21/2016
2   x      wrong             USA    3/21/2016
```

I want to make the id column boolean only and if value is not boolean, delete the row.

i tried

```
df=df[df['id'].bool()]
```

but got `valueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can try convert column `id` [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and then compare with `1`:

```
print pd.to_numeric(df.id, errors='coerce') == 1
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

print df[pd.to_numeric(df.id, errors='coerce') == 1]
  id       text country   datetime
0  1  hello bye     USA  3/20/2016
```

If you need remove rows, where in column `id` is not `0` or `1`, use  [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print df.id.isin(['0','1'])
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

print df[df.id.isin(['0','1'])]
  id          text country   datetime
0  1     hello bye     USA  3/20/2016
1  0  good morning      UK  3/21/2016
```

Or [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
print pd.to_numeric(df.id, errors='coerce').notnull()
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

print df[pd.to_numeric(df.id, errors='coerce').notnull()]
  id          text country   datetime
0  1     hello bye     USA  3/20/2016
1  0  good morning      UK  3/21/2016
```

Last you can convert column `id` to `bool` by [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or double [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print df.loc[df.id.isin(['0','1']),'id'].replace({'0': False, '1': True})
0     True
1    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

print df.loc[df.id.isin(['0','1']),'id'].astype(int).astype(bool)
0     True
1    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

print df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.id, errors='coerce').notnull(),'id'].astype(int).astype(bool)
0     True
1    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

**Timings**, if values for converting to `bool` are `0` and `1` only:

```
#len(df) = 30k
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [628]: %timeit df.loc[np.in1d(df['id'], ['0','1']),'id'].map({'0': False, '1': True})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.19 ms per loop

In [629]: %timeit df.loc[np.in1d(df['id'], ['0','1']),'id'].replace({'0': False, '1': True})
The slowest run took 4.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.72 ms per loop

In [630]: %timeit df.loc[df['id'].isin(['0','1']),'id'].map({'0': False, '1': True})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop

In [631]: %timeit df.loc[df['id'].str.contains('0|1'),'id'].map({'0': False, '1': True})
10 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop

In [632]: %timeit df.loc[df['id'].isin(['0','1']),'id'].astype(int).astype(bool)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.5 ms per loop
```

The best is [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [628]: %timeit df.loc[np.in1d(df['id'], ['0','1']),'id'].map({'0': False, '1': True})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.19 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) to check whether your `id` column contains only digits and then convert to numeric and then to boolean:

```
In [14]: df['id'].str.isdigit()
Out[14]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: id, dtype:
```

To subset with only digits:

```
In [15]: df.loc[df['id'].str.isdigit(), 'id']
Out[15]:
0    1
1    0
Name: id, dtype: object
```

To convert to bool:

```
In [17]: df.loc[df['id'].str.isdigit(), 'id'].astype(int).astype(bool)
Out[17]:
0     True
1    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Comparison with `pd.to_numeric`:

```
In [18]: %timeit pd.to_numeric(df.id, errors='coerce').notnull()
10000 loops, best of 3: 178 us per loop

In [19]: %timeit df['id'].str.isdigit()
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 us per loop
```